# How can I change name of arbitrary columns in pandas df using lambda function?

Tags: python, lambda, pandas, rename

Is there any way to change some column names in pandas dataframe using `lambda`, but not all? For example, suppose that this data frame has columns whose name are `osx`, `centos`, `ubunto`, `windows`. In this data frame, I want to replace all column names with that column name appended by `x`, so in this case, I can rename the column name by:

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: x+'x')
```

However, if I want to rename all column names other than `ubunto`, how can I do it? So what I want to get is data frame whose name is `osxx`, `centosx`, `ubunto`, `windowsx`. Actually, my true data frame has much more columns, so I don't like to write out one-by-one using usual dictionary syntax and instead want to lean on `lambda` function if it's feasible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A [ternary operator](http://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-308.html) might achieve your goal:

```
os_list = ['osxx', 'centos', 'windowsx']    
df.rename(columns=lambda x: x+'x' if x in os_list else x)
```