# Rename specific column(s) in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename

I've got a dataframe called `data`. How would I rename the only one column header? For example `gdp` to `log(gdp)`?

```
data =
    y  gdp  cap
0   1    2    5
1   2    3    9
2   8    7    2
3   3    4    7
4   6    7    7
5   4    8    3
6   8    2    8
7   9    9   10
8   6    6    4
9  10   10    7
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Renaming columns in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas)

Answer (score 618, accepted):

```
data.rename(columns={'gdp':'log(gdp)'}, inplace=True)
```

The [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html#pandas.DataFrame.rename) show that it accepts a dict as a param for `columns` so you just pass a dict with a single entry.

Also see [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas)

Comment: that was surprising. It's a fine way to do it but I had not seen too many Pandas api's using dict's as values

Answer (score 48):

A much faster implementation would be to use `list-comprehension` if you need to rename a single column.

```
df.columns = ['log(gdp)' if x=='gdp' else x for x in df.columns]
```

If the need arises to rename multiple columns, either use conditional expressions like:

```
df.columns = ['log(gdp)' if x=='gdp' else 'cap_mod' if x=='cap' else x for x in df.columns]
```

Or, construct a mapping using a `dictionary` and perform the `list-comprehension` with it's `get` operation by setting default value as the old name:

```
col_dict = {'gdp': 'log(gdp)', 'cap': 'cap_mod'}   ## key→old name, value→new name

df.columns = [col_dict.get(x, x) for x in df.columns]
```

**Timings:**

```
%%timeit
df.rename(columns={'gdp':'log(gdp)'}, inplace=True)
10000 loops, best of 3: 168 µs per loop

%%timeit
df.columns = ['log(gdp)' if x=='gdp' else x for x in df.columns]
10000 loops, best of 3: 58.5 µs per loop
```

Comment: It's kind of odd that this is faster.  I'm assuming that you're using the DataFrame from the question which only has 3 columns (y, gdp, and  cap).  If you use a much larger number of columns, is the list-comprehension version still about 3 times faster than the using rename? or does one version become much faster than the other?

Comment: @LelandHepworth I find it doubtful the Pandas authors were concerned over the number of microseconds it took to rename a column.

Comment: A much faster than what ?

Answer (score 31):

> ## How do I rename a specific column in pandas?

From v0.24+, to rename one (or more) columns at a time,

- **[`DataFrame.rename()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)** with **`axis=1`** or **`axis='columns'`** (the `axis` argument was introduced in `v0.21`.
- **[`Index.str.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)** for string/regex based replacement.

If you need to rename ALL columns at once,

- **[`DataFrame.set_axis()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html)** method with `axis=1`. Pass a list-like sequence. Options are available for in-place modification as well.

---

#### `rename` with `axis=1`

```
df = pd.DataFrame('x', columns=['y', 'gdp', 'cap'], index=range(5))
df

   y gdp cap
0  x   x   x
1  x   x   x
2  x   x   x
3  x   x   x
4  x   x   x
```

With 0.21+, you can now specify an `axis` parameter with `rename`:

```
df.rename({'gdp':'log(gdp)'}, axis=1)
# df.rename({'gdp':'log(gdp)'}, axis='columns')
    
   y log(gdp) cap
0  x        x   x
1  x        x   x
2  x        x   x
3  x        x   x
4  x        x   x
```

(Note that `rename` is not in-place by default, so you will need to **assign the result back**.)

This addition has been made to improve consistency with the rest of the API. The new `axis` argument is analogous to the `columns` parameter—they do the same thing.

```
df.rename(columns={'gdp': 'log(gdp)'})

   y log(gdp) cap
0  x        x   x
1  x        x   x
2  x        x   x
3  x        x   x
4  x        x   x
```

`rename` also accepts a callback that is called once for each column.

```
df.rename(lambda x: x[0], axis=1)
# df.rename(lambda x: x[0], axis='columns')

   y  g  c
0  x  x  x
1  x  x  x
2  x  x  x
3  x  x  x
4  x  x  x
```

For this specific scenario, you would want to use

```
df.rename(lambda x: 'log(gdp)' if x == 'gdp' else x, axis=1)
```

---

#### [`Index.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

Similar to `replace` method of strings in python, pandas Index and Series (object dtype only) define a ("vectorized") `str.replace` method for string and regex-based replacement.

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('gdp', 'log(gdp)')
df
 
   y log(gdp) cap
0  x        x   x
1  x        x   x
2  x        x   x
3  x        x   x
4  x        x   x
```

The advantage of this over the other methods is that `str.replace` supports regex (enabled by default). See the docs for more information.

---

#### Passing a list to `set_axis` with `axis=1`

Call `set_axis` with a list of header(s). The list must be equal in length to the columns/index size. `set_axis` mutates the original DataFrame by default, but you can specify `inplace=False` to return a modified copy.

```
df.set_axis(['cap', 'log(gdp)', 'y'], axis=1, inplace=False)
# df.set_axis(['cap', 'log(gdp)', 'y'], axis='columns', inplace=False)

  cap log(gdp)  y
0   x        x  x
1   x        x  x
2   x        x  x
3   x        x  x
4   x        x  x
```

Note: In future releases, `inplace` will default to `True`.

**Method Chaining**
Why choose `set_axis` when we already have an efficient way of assigning columns with `df.columns = ...`? As shown by Ted Petrou in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46912050/4909087) `set_axis` is useful when trying to chain methods.

Compare

```
# new for pandas 0.21+
df.some_method1()
  .some_method2()
  .set_axis()
  .some_method3()
```

Versus

```
# old way
df1 = df.some_method1()
        .some_method2()
df1.columns = columns
df1.some_method3()
```

The former is more natural and free flowing syntax.

Comment: You could also add `inplace=True` to make the `.replace` method place-in. Then you do not need to assign it back.

Answer (score 9):

There are at least five different ways to rename specific columns in pandas, and I have listed them below along with links to the original answers. I also timed these methods and found them to perform about the same (though YMMV depending on your data set and scenario). The test case below is to rename columns `A` `M` `N` `Z` to `A2` `M2` `N2` `Z2` in a dataframe with columns `A` to `Z` containing a million rows.

```
# Import required modules
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import timeit

# Create sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,9999,size=(1000000, 26)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'))

# Standard way - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19758398/452587
def method_1():
    df_renamed = df.rename(columns={'A': 'A2', 'M': 'M2', 'N': 'N2', 'Z': 'Z2'})

# Lambda function - https://stackoverflow.com/a/16770353/452587
def method_2():
    df_renamed = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x + '2' if x in ['A', 'M', 'N', 'Z'] else x)

# Mapping function - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19758398/452587
def rename_some(x):
    if x=='A' or x=='M' or x=='N' or x=='Z':
        return x + '2'
    return x
def method_3():
    df_renamed = df.rename(columns=rename_some)

# Dictionary comprehension - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58143182/452587
def method_4():
    df_renamed = df.rename(columns={col: col + '2' for col in df.columns[
        np.asarray([i for i, col in enumerate(df.columns) if 'A' in col or 'M' in col or 'N' in col or 'Z' in col])
    ]})

# Dictionary comprehension - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38101084/452587
def method_5():
    df_renamed = df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df[['A', 'M', 'N', 'Z']], ['A2', 'M2', 'N2', 'Z2'])))

print('Method 1:', timeit.timeit(method_1, number=10))
print('Method 2:', timeit.timeit(method_2, number=10))
print('Method 3:', timeit.timeit(method_3, number=10))
print('Method 4:', timeit.timeit(method_4, number=10))
print('Method 5:', timeit.timeit(method_5, number=10))
```

Output:

```
Method 1: 3.650640267
Method 2: 3.163998427
Method 3: 2.998530871
Method 4: 2.9918436889999995
Method 5: 3.2436501520000007
```

Use the method that is most intuitive to you and easiest for you to implement in your application.

Answer (score 5):

Use the **pandas.DataFrame.rename** funtion.
Check this [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) for description.

```
data.rename(columns = {'gdp': 'log(gdp)'}, inplace = True)
```

If you intend to rename multiple columns then

```
data.rename(columns = {'gdp': 'log(gdp)', 'cap': 'log(cap)', ..}, inplace = True)
```

Comment: repeats previous answers

Answer (score 0):

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: {"My_sample": "My_sample_new_name"}.get(x, x))
```

Comment: brilliant.  thank you.  I ended up using it like this - Works great!
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: {"My_sample": "My_sample_new_name"}.get(x, x))

Comment: @sharon i have got some experience in pandas now and i want to tell, that "df.rename(columns={"My_sample": "My_sample_new_name"})" will do the same. :)

Answer (score -1):

ewe can rename by re—doing the table

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
column_names = mydataframe.columns
for i in range(len(mydataframe)):
  column = mydataframe.iloc[:,i]
  df[column_names[i][:-8]+"desigred_texnt"] = column
print(df.columns)
```