# column name has changed automatically

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to merge two dataframe here is my code :

how i load data :

```
import pandas as pd 
df_population = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Satgiaire 
05/Downloads/population_commune.csv",encoding = 'iso-8859-1')
```

How i merge data

```
df_merged2 = pd.merge(df_population, df_merged, left_on=['CODGEO'],
right_on=['Code_commune_INSEE'],how='inner')
```

it succeed but the name of the column CODGEO has changed and know i have CODGEO_X . I have CODGEO in both data frame and i wanna have only CODGEO WITHOUT X

Result:[image]

Comment: Because you have values that clash in the dfs, so it creates a new column with suffix X and Y to show you where the original values came from. You need to post raw data, code to load the dfs and the desired result as this behaviour is [documented](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#overlapping-value-columns)

Comment: i have only one CODGEO_x in the result. i want CODGEO without x or y. or i wanna merge without duplicating columns.

Comment: Are you sure there is no `CODGEO_Y` also after the merge?

Comment: i just cheked. i found it cause there is a dashed cause i have a lot of columns.  Sorry, so know i have to delete one and change the name of the other? or there is a way to merge without having duplicates columns

Comment: You need to decide what the desired result should be, basically you have a clash of values so you need to decide whether you want the lhs/rhs/all rows from the merge

Comment: i want all rows but without duplicating columns that have same values. like here CODGEO.

Comment: So you don't have CODGEO_Y or Code_commune_INSEE_Y etc.., you can drop either of these and rename: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758364/python-rename-single-column-header-in-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changes to the names that you see are defined by the `suffixes=` kwarg in [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). This option only gets utilized if there are columns of the same name that are not used for the merge. For example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'c': [4,5,6]})
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['b'], right_on=['c'])
   a_x  b  a_y  c
0    1  4    1  4
1    2  5    2  5
2    3  6    3  6
```

Whereas:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'c': [4,5,6]})
pd.merge(df1.drop('a', axis=1), df2, left_on=['b'], right_on=['c'])
   b  a  c
0  4  1  4
1  5  2  5
2  6  3  6
```

So you will need to identify columns that you know to be duplicates that you are not using as part of your merge, and drop them from one of your DataFrames.