# Unable rename column series

Tags: python, pandas

I am unable to rename the column of a series:

```
tabla_paso4

Date            decay
2015-06-29    0.003559
2015-09-18    0.025024
2015-08-24    0.037058
2014-11-20    0.037088
2014-10-02    0.037098
Name: decay, dtype: float64
```

I have tried:

```
tabla_paso4.rename('decay_acumul')
tabla_paso4.rename(columns={'decay':'decay_acumul'}
```

I already had a look at the possible duplicate, however don't know why although applying :

```
tabla_paso4.rename(columns={'decay':'decay_acumul'},inplace=True)
```

returns the series like this:

```
Date
2015-06-29    0.003559
2015-09-18    0.025024
2015-08-24    0.037058
2014-11-20    0.037088
2014-10-02    0.037098
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python: rename single column header in pandas dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758364/python-rename-single-column-header-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `tabla_paso4` - is a Series, not a DataFrame.

You can make a DataFrame with named column out of it:

```
new_df = tabla_paso4.to_frame(name='decay_acumul')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
tabla_paso4.columns = ['Date', 'decay_acumul']
```

or

```
tabla_paso4.rename(columns={'decay':'decay_acumul'}, inplace=True)
```

What you were doing wrong earlier, is you missed the `inplace=True` part and therefore the renamed df was returned but not assigned.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Thanos for your help. Don't know why now has no name assigned.