# how can I turn this yfinance data into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yfinance

I'm trying to turn this stock data I got from yfinance into a dataframe. It won't let me call the dates or Adjusted close so I can't merge it into other dataframes I have. This looks simple but i'm really stuck. Hope you can help, thanks!

```
price_history_i = sp.get_price_history('tickername', '2019-12-31', '2020-09-01')['Adj Close']
price_history_a = sp.get_price_history('tickername', '2019-12-31', '2020-09-01')['Adj Close']
price_history_c = sp.get_price_history('tickername', '2019-12-31', '2020-09-01')['Adj Close']

df = pd.DataFrame([price_history_i, price_history_a, price_history_c])
average_price = df.mean()
print(average_price)
```

Output:

```
Date
2019-12-31     9.863333
2020-01-02     9.903333
2020-01-03     9.883333
2020-01-06     9.883333
2020-01-07     9.883333
                ...    
2020-08-25    10.133333
2020-08-26    10.173333
2020-08-27    10.183333
2020-08-28    10.206667
2020-08-31    10.203334
Length: 169, dtype: float64
```

As you can see, the Adj Close isn't listed above the price. I'm using a simple function that I made in the backround that lets me download yfinance info quicker called get_price_history

```
import yfinance as yf



def get_price_history(ticker, sdate, edate):
    data = []
    data = yf.download(ticker, start=sdate, end=edate)
    return (data)
```

Comment: "Adj Close isn't listed above the price" ... Because you didn't name that mean column anything, perhaps? You can use `iloc` to access unnamed columns

Comment: ```TypeError: mean() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'``` when I tried to add the column

Comment: Right... [columns isn't a valid parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html). I meant [rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758364/rename-specific-columns-in-pandas)

Comment: Any chance you could give me an example please?

Comment: `df.mean()` returns a Series. You can rename parts of Series - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename.html

Comment: ohh i see. So the series is names correctly then. But How come when I to_frame() it I don't get a dataframe?

Comment: I'm not seeing that in the question, but one suggestion I have is to make your initial dataframe two columns `[ticker, adj_close]` rather than trying to merge three dataframes horizontally. Otherwise, looks like you're finding the mean of different tickers

Answer (score 1):

Workaround:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.mean(), columns = [df.T.columns[0]])
```

considering that df is laying horizontal (I think it is) and that the name of the columns (are *"adj close"*)

Comment: It looks like the Date and Adj Close aren't on the same line. Like the Adj Close fits well above the  prices whiles the Date is right above the dates. I'm confused because It's still not in a dataframe. The reason I care so much is because I'm trying to align multiple dataframes with the same dates and I need to calculate everything together.

Comment: Date is `Index` while adj... is a `column`. You see the correct thing and is supposed to be like this

Comment: I see!!! So how can I turn the date from an index into a column and have the index = 0,1,2,3...etc