# Element error: Expecting 12 elements, new element value is 8

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 5 columns and 100 values. I am trying to do a basic descriptive analysis on the data before I go further. I am doing this by creating a function where the different descriptive information is found and stored in a new dataframe, but I am getting an element error.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display

df = pd.read_excel('cmc_data.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
print(df)

def detailed_analysis(data, pred = None):
    obs = data.shape[0]
    types = data.dtypes
    counts = data.apply(lambda x: x.count())
    uniques = data.apply(lambda x: [x.unique])
    nulls = data.apply(lambda x: x.isnull().sum())
    distincts = data.apply(lambda x: x.unique().shape[0])
    missing_ratio = (nulls / obs)*100
    skewness = data.skew()
    kurtosis = data.kurt()
    print('Data shape:', data.shape)

    if pred is None:
        cols = ['types', 'counts', 'nulls', 'distincts', 'missing ratio', 'uniques', 'skewness', 'kurtosis']
        details = pd.concat([types, counts, nulls, distincts, missing_ratio, uniques, skewness, kurtosis], axis=1)
    else:
        corr = data.corr()[pred]
        details = pd.concat([types, counts, nulls, distincts, missing_ratio, uniques, skewness, kurtosis, corr], axis=1
                            , sort=False)
        corr_col = 'corr' + pred
        cols = ['types', 'counts', 'nulls', 'distincts', 'missing ratio', 'uniques', 'skewness', 'kurtosis', corr_col]


    details.columns = cols
    dtypes = details.types.value_counts()
    print('____________________________\nData types:\n', dtypes)
    print('____________________________')
    return details

details = detailed_analysis(df)
display(details)
```

My error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ejer/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/CMC_3.py", line 38, in <module>
    details = detailed_analysis(df)
  File "C:/Users/Ejer/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/CMC_3.py", line 32, in detailed_analysis
    details.columns = cols
  File "C:\Users\Ejer\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5152, in __setattr__
    return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
  File "pandas\_libs\properties.pyx", line 66, in pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty.__set__
  File "C:\Users\Ejer\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 564, in _set_axis
    self._mgr.set_axis(axis, labels)
  File "C:\Users\Ejer\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 226, in set_axis
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 12 elements, new values have 8 elements

Process finished with exit code 1
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 12 elements, new values have 8 elements
```

Comment: Which line produces the error?

Comment: I updated my question. Does not really specify what line in my code, or atleast I cant tell

Comment: The problem is in the line `details.columns = cols`. So, this means that the number of columns in details is 12, while the number passed is 8. Do recheck the details dataframe, by using `display(details)`.

Comment: @Dfhaa_DK Can you add a snippet of the `xlsx` file as text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is at this line:

```
details.columns = cols
```

cols has 8 elements, while df has 12 columns, so it cannot assign the new column names. If you want to change some column names but not all of them, you must add the rest of the 12 column names of the df, into cols.

To make things easier, first of all get the column names of the df with this:

```
print(df.columns)
```

and work on it by copying, pasting, etc

Comment: Ok, but my original dataframe (df) has 5 columns. Where does the 12 come from exactly?

Comment: What is the result of `print(df.columns)` ?

Comment: What is it's shape? As in rows and columns?

Comment: The shape is 100 rows and 5 columns

Comment: In any case, your code will not work, even with 5 columns. When you assign new column names as list, the length of the list must be equal with the length of df.columns. Alternatively you can rename specific columns only, by using df.rename. Check here how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758364/rename-specific-columns-in-pandas