# Changing the names of columns generated by get_dummies in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to create a `dummies` of the categorical variable `"SEX"` in my dataset. I want to change the names of generated `dummy` columns . But I could see there is an option of changing only the prefix of column name but couldn't find any way to change the entire name. Can anyone help me out?

[image]

My code for the above output is:

```
print(df['SEX'].value_counts())

dummy_variable=pd.get_dummies(df['SEX']).rename(columns=lambda x:'SEX_' +str(x))

print(dummy_variable)
```

I desired to have the output dummy column names as `SEX_MALE` and `SEX_FEMALE`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename specific column(s) in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758364/rename-specific-columns-in-pandas)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11346283

Comment: Well if you wanna rename columns automatically generated by get_dummies, I suggest you use the get_dummies(data['column_name'], prefix = 'pre_') You can add fstrings to this to generate names dynamically.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
df = df.rename(columns = {'SEX_1': 'SEX_MALE', 'SEX_2': 'SEX_FEMALE'})
```

Comment: Hi Naman, Is there any way to change the names in dummy variable itself.i mean before adding to dataset.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but by doing this you should be able to change the columns names:

```
dummy_variable.rename(columns = {'SEX_1': 'SEX_MALE', 'SEX_2': 'SEX_FEMALE'}, inplace = False)
```